# what sobjects are supported in a queue

Tags: sobject, queue

What objects can in include in Queues? Online i can see only these objects can be in included in a Queue: Cases, Leads, Tasks, Contact requests, Orders, Service contracts, Knowledge articles and Custom objects.

But Although i can include most other objects, like Broadcast Topic, some others i cannot, like Account, Opportunity.
So does someone have a definite answer on which objects can after all be in included?

Comment: Do you mean what standard Sobjects are supported by queue?

Comment: yes, that's my doubt

Answer (score 0):

As the ansswer for this would totally depend on individual org  because of custom object, features, additional licenses or addons or products in your org, the best way to find this out is

1. Go to Quick Find.
2. Type Queue.
3. Try creating a new Queue.

There you can see list of all supported objects

[image]

Comment: I know i can do this. But as most of the Standard object are there, i probably am forgeting some of those exceptions. Because i dont know by heart ALL Salesforce Standard Objects. And that is the list of missing objects is what id like to have